# Unable to get userName because I did not specify userName?

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to run this command

```
$ aws iam  get-user --query 'User.UserName' --output text
```

and it failed with

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetUser operation:
Must specify userName when calling with non-User credentials
```

I thought it might be due to missing profile, so I added a `--profile` parameter.

```
$ aws --profile dev iam get-user --query 'User.UserName' --output text
```

It still fails with the same error.

Since I have enabled MFA, is it possible it is due to a mistyped token from the authenicator? If so, can I reset the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `query` parameter for the `get-user` command in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html)

It should be possible to query for a user name with the `user-name` parameter.

```
aws iam get-user --user-name Bob
```

The [get-current-user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workdocs/get-current-user.html) command

> Retrieves details of the current user for whom the authentication token was generated.

which might be what you are looking for. If you don't specify the `profile` the aws cli will use the default profile from the credentials file.